# How I can fix this message with my applet?

Tags: java, applet, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

I have an error when I run my Applet:

```
Ignored exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Ignored exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    Could not initialize class com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher
```

Comment: 1) What is the HTML used to launch the applet?  2) Is the applet at a publicly available URL where we can see it fail?  I can generally solve these things within 5 minutes of seeing the 'live' applet page.

Comment: Hi this es the url [link](http://www.disrayco.com/applet/dist/applet.html) and thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems from the link that the Digital Persona API was not added to the `archive` attribute of the applet element.  It also seems (from other questions) to be code that needs to be digitally signed and trusted.  Fun times ahead!

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see some code but I would look at your static variables being initialized and your class `com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher`

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should provide more information: stack trace, applet tag, etc.

But I can assume the following. The class that cannot be initialized belongs to package `...jni...`. Does it indeed mean that it performs JNI calls? If it is correct your applet cannot work unless you sign it. Applets are running in controlled environment and cannot do a lot of operations that are forbidden for security reasons. JNI calls belong to this type of operations.

So, double check: if your applet performs JNI calls you should either find other solution or sign it.

Comment: Hi this es the url [link](http://www.disrayco.com/applet/dist/applet.html) and thanks for your help.